# How to open the ImagePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swiftui

I need to open an image picker in my app using SwiftUI, how can I do that?

I thought about using the `UIImagePickerController`, but I don't know how to do that in SwiftUI.

Comment: Most answers here are unfortunately from Beta period. Here's November 2019 tutorial from @TwoStraws: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/importing-an-image-into-swiftui-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cleaned up version for Xcode 12 available via SPM as Swift Package:

https://github.com/ralfebert/ImagePickerView

Source:

```swift
import SwiftUI

public struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    private let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    public init(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
    }

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = self.sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(
            onDismiss: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() },
            onImagePicked: self.onImagePicked
        )
    }

    final public class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        private let onDismiss: () -> Void
        private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void

        init(onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
            self.onDismiss = onDismiss
            self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
        }

        public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.onImagePicked(image)
            }
            self.onDismiss()
        }

        public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.onDismiss()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can this determine if the file type is lets say .png vs ,jpeg... for later upload to like firebase storage?

Answer (score 51):

You need to wrap `UIImagePickerController` in a struct implementing `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

For more about `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, please check this amazing WWDC 2019 talk:

[Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231)

```swift
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    private var presentationMode

    let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void

    final class Coordinator: NSObject,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate,
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @Binding
        private var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        private let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
        private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void

        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>,
             sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType,
             onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            self.sourceType = sourceType
            self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            onImagePicked(uiImage)
            presentationMode.dismiss()

        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode,
                           sourceType: sourceType,
                           onImagePicked: onImagePicked)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }

}
```

Here's a simple view to test it:

- The picker is displayed in a sheet
- the selected image appears without any sort of animation, and replaces the `Show image picker` button

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: Image? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showImagePicker.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Show image picker")
                }
                image?.resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                    self.image = Image(uiImage: image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps as a starting point!

I'm sure Apple will make this easier to do once `SwiftUI` is out of beta.

[image]

**Tested on Xcode 11.4**

**Bugs:**

- @JAHelia found a bug on the picker when `sourceType` is not the camera.
  You won't be able to drag down the sheet - I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Thanks!
But there is a problem with the NavigationBar: https://imgur.com/a/TIeX1mN

Comment: @Shahar as I said, it's rough around the edges - I don't think we're supposed to present an image picker like that. Apple will eventually release the right API to do this. Also, the` UIImagePickerController` is a navigation controller, so you might want to hide the SwiftUI one, otherwise you will have two navigation controllers.

Comment: This no longer works in Xcode 11 beta 4: "Cannot assign to property: '$isShown' is immutable. Cannot assign to property: '$image' is immutable"

Comment: To get it to work in beta 4 just do what they did here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120034. That is change @binding to Binding<Type>. Then when you set the values use image.value = Image(uiImage: uiImage)

Comment: Working fine on XCode 11.2

Comment: there is a bug with UIImagePickerController where it can't be dismissed by dragging down before choosing any image, I've posted a question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485214/swiftui-cant-drag-down-to-dismiss-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: @JAHelia Indeed, I haven't found a workaround yet - you can only drag down the sheet if you're selecting the camera as the source.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but if user wanted to remove/delete the photo they just took with camera or selected from library, how would they go about that?

Answer (score 16):

Based on @user:2890168 I made a version that:

- retrieves `UIImage` instead of `Image`
- use `.sheet` to present the `ImagePicker`.
- shows `ActionSheet` to help users to remove or change the image.

[image]

```
struct LibraryImage: View {

    @State var showAction: Bool = false
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false

    @State var uiImage: UIImage? = nil

    var sheet: ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Action"),
            message: Text("Quotemark"),
            buttons: [
                .default(Text("Change"), action: {
                    self.showAction = false
                    self.showImagePicker = true
                }),
                .cancel(Text("Close"), action: {
                    self.showAction = false
                }),
                .destructive(Text("Remove"), action: {
                    self.showAction = false
                    self.uiImage = nil
                })
            ])

    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            if (uiImage == nil) {
                Image(systemName: "camera.on.rectangle")
                    .accentColor(Color.App.purple)
                    .background(
                        Color.App.gray
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .cornerRadius(6))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                    }
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showAction = true
                    }
            }

        }

        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, onDismiss: {
            self.showImagePicker = false
        }, content: {
            ImagePicker(isShown: self.$showImagePicker, uiImage: self.$uiImage)
        })

        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showAction) {
            sheet
        }
    }
}
```

The default `body` of `LibraryImage` is an `Image` that shows a camera icon that is tappable by the users.

On tap event, the image picker is shown with a `sheet` modifier. After the image selection, the `LibraryImage` body is recomputed and now shows the `Image` defined in else statement (because `uiImage` property now contains the image picked by the user).

Now, on tap event the `ActionSheet` is shown.

The edited image picker:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var uiImage: UIImage?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var isShown: Bool
        @Binding var uiImage: UIImage?

        init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, uiImage: Binding<UIImage?>) {
            _isShown = isShown
            _uiImage = uiImage
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let imagePicked = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            uiImage = imagePicked
            isShown = false
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            isShown = false
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(isShown: $isShown, uiImage: $uiImage)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }

}
```

default behaviour:

[image]

Comment: The `UIImagePickerController` [appears to not use the whole sheet area](https://imgur.com/a/CdpAGak). How to make sure the view controller adapts to the sheet?

Comment: Just as sidenote: [the `UIImagePickerController ` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) states that a popover should be used (which did not make a difference in my case, though).

Answer (score 8):

iOS 14 Xcode 12 - Photo Picker  SwiftUI with Reusable View with limits allowed

```
struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var images: [UIImage]
    @Binding var showPicker: Bool
    var selectionLimit: Int
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        config.selectionLimit = selectionLimit
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

        var parent: ImagePickerView
        
        init(parent: ImagePickerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            parent.showPicker.toggle()
            
            for img in results {
                if img.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                    img.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, err) in
                        guard let image1 = image else { return }
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.parent.images.append(image1 as! UIImage)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle Error
                    parent.showPicker.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in View you can do

```
VStack {          
    Image(systemName: "camera.viewfinder")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.viewModel.pickerBool.toggle()
        }
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$viewModel.pickerBool) {
    ImagePickerView(images: self.$viewModel.images, showPicker: self.$viewModel.pickerBool, selectionLimit: 3)
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't forget to `import PhotosUI`

Answer (score 8):

We can use [**PhotosPicker**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker) since **iOS** 16.0, **iPadOS** 16.0, **macOS** 13.0, **watchOS** 9.0 and above.

Simple example:

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct MediaView: View {
    @State private var photosPickerPresented = false
    @State private var photoPickerItems = [PhotosPickerItem]()

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // Present photo Picker
            photosPickerPresented.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Show Photos Picker")
        }
        .photosPicker(isPresented: $photosPickerPresented, selection: $photoPickerItems)
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: Don't forget to `import PhotosUI` (like me), else `.photosPicker` won't be available.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that works in Xcode 11 beta 4.

It uses a BindableObject singleton (ImagePicker.shared) with two properties: .view and .image.

See usage below (ImagePickerTestView)

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class ImagePicker : BindableObject {

    static let shared : ImagePicker = ImagePicker()

    private init() {}  //force using the singleton: ImagePicker.shared

    let view = ImagePicker.View()
    let coordinator = ImagePicker.Coordinator()

    // Bindable Object part
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Image?, Never>()

    @Published var image: Image? = nil {
        didSet {
            if image != nil {
                willChange.send(image)
            }
        }
    }
}


extension ImagePicker {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        // UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            ImagePicker.shared.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            picker.dismiss(animated:true)
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated:true)
        }
    }


    struct View: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            ImagePicker.shared.coordinator
        }

        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker.View>) -> UIImagePickerController {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator
            return picker
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                    context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker.View>) {

        }

    }

}


struct ImagePickerTestView: View {

    @State var showingPicker = false

    @State var image : Image? = nil
    // you could use ImagePicker.shared.image directly

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show image picker") {
                self.showingPicker = true
            }

            image?
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 300)

        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingPicker,
                onDismiss: {
                    // do whatever you need here
                }, content: {
                    ImagePicker.shared.view
                })
        .onReceive(ImagePicker.shared.$image) { image in
            // This gets called when the image is picked.
            // sheet/onDismiss gets called when the picker completely leaves the screen
            self.image = image
        }
    }

}

#if DEBUG
struct ImagePicker_Previews : PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ImagePickerTestView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: BindableObject is now ObservableObject

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new at Swift, but I was able to get it with the following.

This will load up an image picker modal and let you select a photo, and it will then update an `@State` variable from a parent.

If this works for you, you can replace the `@State` with something that can span across multiple components, such as `@EnvironmentObject` so other components can get updated as well.

Hope this helps!

```
// ImagePicker.swift

struct ImagePicker : View {   
    @State var image: UIImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ImagePickerViewController(image: $image)
    }
}
```

```
// ImagePickerViewController.swift

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI


struct ImagePickerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerViewController>) {
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerViewController>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

        var parent: ImagePickerViewController

        init(_ parent: ImagePickerViewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let imagePicked = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage            
            parent.image = imagePicked
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// SampleView.swift

struct SampleView : View {
    var body: some View {
        PresentationLink(destination: ImagePicker().environmentObject(self.userData), label: {
           Text("Import Photo")
       })
    }
}
```

Once again, I am fresh into Swift so if anyone has some comments, please let me know! Happy to learn more.

Comment: What is self.userData?  It's an observable object but what exactly conforms to observable object that would make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a version that I think is more general and extensible. I used a `Subject` instead of a `Binding` to solve the problem where it's undoable/inappropriate to add another Binding in your view.

**For example, you created a `List` showing a set of images stored in the underlying storage and you wanted to add an image with the image picker. In this case, it's very hard/ugly to have that image added to your underlying storage.**

So I used a subject to transfer the image and you can simply observe it and add the new images to some storage, or if you want it to behave just like a Binding, it's one line of code, too. (modifying your State in your observation)

Then I wrapped the preferences into a `ViewModel` so it won't get cluttered if you want to have more subjects or configurations.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ImagePickerView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var model: ImagePickerViewModel

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIImagePickerController {

        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        controller.allowsEditing = false
        controller.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        return controller

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) {
        // run right after making

    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        var parentView: ImagePickerView

        init(_ parentView: ImagePickerView) {
            self.parentView = parentView
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parentView.model.isPresented = false
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {

            guard let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

            let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            parentView.model.pickedImagesSubject?.send([image])
            parentView.model.isPresented = false

        }

    }

}

struct ImagePickerViewModel {
    var isPresented: Bool = false
    let pickedImagesSubject: PassthroughSubject<[Image], Never>! = PassthroughSubject<[Image], Never>()
}
```

Usage:

```
struct SomeView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var storage: Storage
    @State var imagePickerViewModel = ImagePickerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.imagePickerViewModel.isPresented.toggle() }) { ... }
            .sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerViewModel.isPresented) {
                ImagePickerView(model: self.$imagePickerViewModel)
            }
            .onReceive(imagePickerViewModel.pickedImagesSubject) { (images: [Image]) -> Void in
                withAnimation {
                    // modify your storage here
                    self.storage.images += images
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this:

```
    import SwiftUI

    final class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject {

        @Binding var image: UIImage?
        @Binding var takePhoto: Bool

        init(image: Binding<UIImage?>, takePhoto: Binding<Bool>) {
            _image = image
            _takePhoto = takePhoto
        }
    }

    struct ShowImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

        @Binding var image: UIImage?
        @Binding var takePhoto: Bool

        func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator {
            ImagePickerCoordinator(image: $image, takePhoto: $takePhoto)
        }

        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {

            let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerController.delegate = context.coordinator

            guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) else { return pickerController }

            switch self.takePhoto {
            case true:
                pickerController.sourceType = .camera
            case false:
                pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            }

            pickerController.allowsEditing = true
            return pickerController
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
    }

    extension ImagePickerCoordinator: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            guard let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

            self.image = uiImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}
```

Add the logic of just two buttons to your View that's enough...))