# How to pick image from gallery in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swiftui

I tried to make a SwiftUI class that conforms to UIViewRepresentable and implements makeUIView and updateUIView. 
But not able to complete it.Here is code :

Code:

```
struct ImagePicker : UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var image: UIImage

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @Binding var image: UIImage

    init(image: Binding<UIImage>) {
        $image = image
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {


        if let possibleImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            image = possibleImage
        } else if let possibleImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            image = possibleImage
        } else {

        }
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(image: $image)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImageView {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return imageview
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView,
                  context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    uiView.image = image
}

}
```

I tried imagePicker as control but unable to use.

Comment: I *had* a working version of `UIImagePickerController`. Looking at your code, you're close. But. First off, what do you mean by "it isn't working". (More details would be helpful.) Next, my version is based off of the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515871/how-to-open-the-imagepicker-in-swiftui BUT FINALLY - sorry for the shouting - my version, that version, and I'm guessing your version are all broken in beta 4, which was released three days ago. What version of everything are you running?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your answer is worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using `presentationMode` here, to check for the view that is it presenting or not?

By using this you can `dismiss()` the `UIImagePickerController`.

Sample code for SwiftUI preview:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isShowPicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: Image? = Image("placeholder")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    image?
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(height: 320)
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.isShowPicker.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("IMPORT").font(.headline)
                    }.foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPicker) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$image)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Pick Image")
        }
    }
}


struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode

    @Binding var image: Image?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        @Binding var image: Image?

        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            _image = image
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            presentationMode.dismiss()

        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode, image: $image)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }

}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image variable in the parent class does not fill after the user selects the image.

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI is finally getting its own native **photo picker** view in **iOS 16.** The PhotosPicker view supports all the common functionalities that PHPickerViewController provide like **single** and **multiple selections**, asset type filtering, and album switching are all included.

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    //@State private var selectedItem: [PhotosPickerItem] = [PhotosPickerItem]() // use to select multiple images from gallery
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    @State private var selectedImageData: Data? = nil
    
    //MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                PhotosPicker(
                    selection: $selectedItem,
                   // maxSelectionCount: 2, //set max selection from gallery
                    matching: .images,
                    photoLibrary: .shared()
                ) {
                    Text("Choose Photos from Gallery")
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 50)
                        .background(Capsule().stroke(lineWidth: 2))
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newValue in
                    Task { // Incase of multiple selection newValue is of array type
                        if let data = try? await newValue?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            selectedImageData = data
                        }
                    }
                }
            if let selectedImageData, let uiImage = UIImage(data: selectedImageData) {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 8)
                    )
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Sample ss**

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pls try This one

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OpenGallary: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let isShown: Binding<Bool>
    let image: Binding<Image?>

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        let isShown: Binding<Bool>
        let image: Binding<Image?>

        init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            self.isShown = isShown
            self.image = image
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            self.image.wrappedValue = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            self.isShown.wrappedValue = false
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            isShown.wrappedValue = false
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(isShown: isShown, image: image)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<OpenGallary>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<OpenGallary>) {

    }
}
```

the picker is displayed right on top of the view, without transition
the selected image appears without any sort of animation, and replaces the Show image picker button

After that create display view in which you can call show this imagePicker

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showImagePicker.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Show image picker")
                }
                image?.resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            if (showImagePicker) {
                OpenGallary(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2023 version

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct TestImagePicker: View {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    @State private var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @State private var imageData: [PhotosPickerItem: Data] = [:]
    
    //MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(
                selection: $selectedItems,
                maxSelectionCount: 2,
                matching: .images,
                photoLibrary: .shared()
            ) {
                Text("Choose Photos from Gallery")
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedItems) { newValue in
                for item in newValue {
                    Task {
                        if let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            imageData[item] = data
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(Array(imageData.keys), id: \.self) { item in
                        if let data = imageData[item], let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```