# SwiftUI - can't init the coordinator for my representable view

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to integrate a UISegmentedControl into my view, which works fine. But I want to update the SwiftUI ContentView when the control's index changes.

For this purpose I want to create a Coordinator for accessing the ContentView's State through a Binding.

I followed the official

> [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231)

(relevant from min 13:37), but it throws out an error saying "Cannot assign to property: '$textString' is immutable" when I try to implement the init function of the Coordinator class.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct SegControl: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject {

        @Binding var textString: String

        init(textString: Binding<String>) {
            //Error: Cannot assign to property: '$textString' is immutable
            $textString = textString
        }

        @objc func testFunc() {
            textString = "Updated!"
        }

    }


    @Binding var textString: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(textString: $textString)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISegmentedControl {
        return UISegmentedControl(items: ["One", "Two"])
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISegmentedControl, context: Context) {
        uiView.center = uiView.center
        uiView.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        uiView.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.testFunc), for: .valueChanged)
    }


}
```

Comment: Beta 4 broke my `UIImagePickerController` port. It was based on this question, and I see that the answer's been updated for the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515871/how-to-open-the-imagepicker-in-swiftui/57160706#57160706 Hopefully this helps you. Remember, basically `UIViewRepresentable` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable` are the same thing - a single SwiftUI `View`.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973959/swiftui-how-to-implement-a-custom-init-with-binding-variables, but the TL;DR is just to replace the $ with _, like so: $textString = textString // beta 3 _textString = textString // beta 4