# SwiftUI: can't drag-down to dismiss UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using the following piece of code to show the default `UIImagePickerController`, but it seems that the the `iOS 13`'s drag-down to dismiss gesture isn't working with `UIImagePickerController` wrapped in a `SwiftUI` view, the user still can hit the default `Cancel` tab bar item in order to dismiss the picker, the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap To show modal")
        .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showModal.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            SomeUIKitView()
        }
    }
}

final class SomeUIKitViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        return imagePicker
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
}

struct SomeUIKitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SomeUIKitViewControllerWrapper()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe that one supports it? Didn't test it yet https://github.com/egeniq/BetterSheet

Comment: I tried it but the same issue happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own drag down in SwiftUI. In your case you could try to implement it for your SomeUIKitView() view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIDragDown: View {
  @State private var dragDownTreshhold: CGFloat = 50
  @State private var draggedDistance: CGFloat = 0
  @State private var dragDownOffsetY: CGFloat = 0


  var body: some View {
    Text("Drag me")
      .offset(x: 0, y: dragDownOffsetY + draggedDistance)
      .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
      .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
          .onChanged { value in
            print("dragged by" , value.translation.height)
            self.draggedDistance = value.translation.height
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
          if self.draggedDistance > self.dragDownTreshhold {
            self.dragDownOffsetY = 600
          } else {
            self.draggedDistance = 0
            self.dragDownOffsetY = 0
          }
        }
    )
  }
}

struct SwiftUIDragDown_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    SwiftUIDragDown()
  }
}
```